# host a site on home server

Tags: port-forwarding, windows-home-server, web-hosting

I have a running home server (using Windows 7), and inside the LAN I can surf the site. I have made the necessary changes in the firewall and forwarding the port in router.

Sadly,  when I try to get the site from outside the LAN by the external ip (and the port I'm forwarding),  I can't reach the site. like it doesn't exist.

I'm pretty sure I did the forwarding right, because when I try to surf the web from a computer in the LAN, and use the router external ip (and the port), I get my website.

All the guides stops here. I have search the web for days - and nothing.

I know it doesn't matter, but I tried apache2.4 , tomcat, xampp and even built my own server with Java - none of them worked outside of the LAN

Comment: Most likely your ISP blocks incoming connections on port 80 - nothing you can do about.

Comment: Did you try ports other than 80? Something like 8080 or whatever. You only need to modify the port forwarding rule to try this.

Comment: Do you have a true public IP or are you behind CGN? If the latter its game over. Or your forward simply isnt working (some routers require a firewall change first).

Comment: i tried other port - they get the same result. @DanielB

Comment: the ip starts with 84.XXX.X.XX . so, i'm not under CGN. @Linef4ult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, your ISP is blocking port 80.  Port 80 is the standard port used for the web.  ISPs will block port 80, saying that web hosting is a business level service and will charge your more.  Try changing the port in your server to 8080, as well as change your port forwarding.  Then connect to your server in a browser with `:8080` appended to the end.  Once that is done, replace the following with your external IP address and enter it in your browser `http://10.10.10.10:8080`.

You can always check with your ISP to see if they are blocking port 80.  If they are, you can simply use a different port like 8080, or pay for the higher level of service.

Comment: i doesn't seem like it is blocked. allso, i used ports like 8080,4680,1234 from outside the LAN into the router and the router forward it to port 1234 or 8080 and so on . still not working from outside of LAN. @Keltari

Answer (score 0):

Does your internet access point (cable modem, dsl modem) also act as your router, or do you have a second device after that device such as a wireless router? In the case you have two devices it is possible that your setup is actually requiring port forwarding on the external device (the modem) and the internal device (the wireless router), or better yet, to place the external device into a bridge mode that enables your purchased router to be the outermost device on the network as far as routing is concerned.